# How to test npm library having native dependecy

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am new to the world of testing.

I have [react-native-formly npm library](https://github.com/irohitb/rn-formly) written entirely in javascript but have a component or two which are dependent on native libraries like react-native-image-picker.

Recently, I updated all my dependencies thinking it won't cause any breaking changes but it turned out it actually did.

My primary goal here is to write test cases for the component which require native implementation (test case as simple as app doesn't crash on initialising my component).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Covering Testing Native components:**

As React Native components are written in js and can be tested with `jest` (as your choice of testing suite), we can still test "native" components since those components are wrapped with the js component.

Note: 
All native components are wrapped [native-bridge docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios) such that JS -> communicates with native component.

Therefore, you can still test native components as you would expect from a TDD level.

---

However, as jest or other suites will be unable to render correctly say, the camera module within the js runtime, you will at times have to `mock` those functions.

This can be done with `jest.fn()`

A good reference for testing the `react-native-camera.js` can be found in the [react-native-community docs](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/tests.md)

e.g.

```
  test('test onPress functionality', async () => {
    const onTakePhotoEvent = jest.fn(data => data);
    const wrapper = mount(<PhotoCamera onTakePhoto={onTakePhotoEvent} />);
    await wrapper
      .find(TouchableOpacity)
      .at(1)
      .props()
      .onPress();
    expect(onTakePhotoEvent.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
  });
```